# Scraping Steam Reviews with XMR page, not going to rest of reviews

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My problem is that the parameters are supposed to shift to get to the next 10 reviews and iterate until there are no more reviews left for the game. However the loop prints the same 10 reviews over and over again without going to next 10. Here is the code below. Thanks

```
def review_scraper():
    from alive_progress import alive_bar
    import re
    start_time = time.time()

    url = "https://steamcommunity.com/app/933110/homecontent/"
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36'}
    regex = re.compile('apphub_CardContentAuthorName')
    for x in range(1, 5):
        offset = (x*10) - 10

        payload = {
        'userreviewsoffset': offset,
        'p': x,
        'workshopitemspage': x,
        'readytouseitemspage': x,
        'mtxitemspage': x,
        'itemspage': x,
        'screenshotspage': x,
        'videospage': x,
        'artpage': x,
        'allguidepage': x,
        'webguidepage': x,
        'integratedguidepage': x,
        'discussionspage': x,
        'numperpage': '10',
        'browsefilter': 'mostrecent',
        'browsefilter': 'mostrecent',
        'l': 'english',
        'appHubSubSection': '10',
        'filterLanguage': 'default',
        'searchText': '',
        'forceanon': '1'}
        page = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
        cards = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'apphub_Card modalContentLink interactable'})
        y = 0
        for card in cards:
            title = card.find('div',{'class':'title'}).text
            hours = card.find('div',{'class':'hours'}).text
            content = card.find('div',{'class':'apphub_CardTextContent'}).text.strip()
            author = card.find('div',{'class':regex}).text

            print(title + '\n' + hours + '\n' + content + '\n\n' + 'Author: ' + author + '\n' + '#'*50)
            y = y + 1
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    print(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So incase anyone has the same problem as I had I found the solution. Here is the code listed below.

```
def review_scraper():
    from alive_progress import alive_bar
    import re
    import json
    start_time = time.time()
    z = 0
    url = "https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/933110?json=1&cursor=*"
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    tot_reviews = (response['query_summary']['total_reviews'])
    pages_to_iterate = tot_reviews/20
    pages_to_iterate = round(int(pages_to_iterate))
    cursor = "*"
    for i in range(20):
        url = "https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/933110?json=1&cursor=" + str(cursor)
        response = requests.get(url).json()
        reviews = (response['reviews'])
        cursor = (response['cursor'])
        for x in range(response['query_summary']['num_reviews']):
            print(reviews[x]['review'])
            z = z + 1
    print(z)
```

The only problem is that after 200 or so reviews it will begin to reiterate the same reviews. This is a problem with the cursor not finding the next section around this mark. However this code will get you on your way.